# Changing SAP standard code with access key

Tags: abap, sap-basis

When i try to change the SAP standard code taking the access key from table devaccess, the access key is not recognized why?

[image: Access Key not recognized]

Comment: I would double check that the requested access key really match Object / SAP licence of your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access key is bound always to a specific SAP-installation. You need to obtain this key from SAP.

There is another better way to enhance code of SAP without changing it in the way you want to to.

Check if you can use implicit enhancements or if there are any enhancement points in the code.

That what you want to do is old style and causes always efforts when you update your SAP-Version.

Check out the SAP-Enhancement Framework  -  that is the recommended way to extend standard SAP-Code

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_banking50/helpdata/de/94/9cdc40132a8531e10000000a1550b0/content.htm

Answer (score 2):

I believe the access key is linked to the installation number and object directory entry. The installation number here is *initial*, so that object must not be for this system.